# Python http response stream getting closed prematurely

Tags: python

I'm trying to write simple code that reads lines one by one from a file streamed over http. Here is what I have:

```py
url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1P2hMOGgz9tEN5DYb7rqTE0MeTbgb1Pd5"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
reader = io.TextIOWrapper(response.raw, encoding="utf-8")
line1 = reader.readline()
line2 = reader.readline()
```

This correctly reads the first line, but when trying to read the second line, it blows up with `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

The test file just contains:

```
1
2
3
```

What is causing the underlying stream to get closed prematurely? I see there are alternative solutions that rely on `Response.iter_lines()`, but I'd like to understand why the code that I have doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a `TextIOWrapper` for this, you can just use `iter_lines`:

```py
import requests

for line in requests.get(url, stream=True).iter_lines():
    decoded = line.decode('utf-8')
    # do something with decoded
```

Or to do something similar to the `readline` approach:

```py
lines = requests.get(url, stream=True).iter_lines()

first_line = next(lines, b'')
second_line = next(lines, b'')
...
```

To use a wrapper, I'd use either a BytesIO or StringIO object instead of a `TextIOWrapper`:

```py
from io import BytesIO

lines = requests.get(url, stream=True).iter_lines()

with BytesIO(b''.join(lines)) as fh:
    for line in map(bytes.decode, fh):
        print(line)


## or the StringIO approach
from io import StringIO

lines = requests.get(url, stream=True).iter_lines()
string_lines = ''.join(map(bytes.decode, lines))

with StringIO(string_lines) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line)
```

But these aggregate the content, which might defeat the purpose of streaming, depending on your use case.

### Edit

You could potentially roll your own. Not ideal, but it's not too bad to implement:

```py
class WebReader:
     def __init__(self, stream):
         self.stream = stream

     def __enter__(self):
         return self

     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
         if isinstance(exc_value, Exception):
             return False
         return True

     def __iter__(self):
         return self

     def __next__(self):
         return next(self.stream)

     def read(self):
         return b''.join(self)

     def readline(self):
         return next(self, b'')

     def readlines(self):
         return list(self)


r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with WebReader(r.iter_lines()) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # do something with line
```

Comment: Thanks I will experiment with some of these approaches. Though that still leaves the questions of why it is behaving the way it is with `TextIOWrapper`, as that does not seem to make sense.

Also, note that I'm looking for a solution that processes the file without storing the entire content in memory, so the bottom two approaches use join() would not work.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I figured that would be the case. I'll keep playing around with it to see if there's a better solution

Comment: The proposed `WebReader` class is interesting. I'd just modify it to return decoded utf-8 strings instead of bytes.